# In Excel I need to convert seconds in days hours min sec

Tags: excel, days, seconds

I've already figure out that I can divide the number of seconds/86400 and then use the format: dd \d\a\y\s hh:mm:ss, but when it goes over 31 days 23:59:59, the number of days goes back to 0.

How can I keep on going with the days (like 32 days 00:00:01)?

Thank you

----  Adding more ---

I forgot to mention that I'm trying to do it in a Pivot table and I have not been able to figure out how to use text in it...

I've also found the following format but it won't give me a 00 in the month:
   Nb of seconds: 13670
   Format : yy \y\e\a\r\s MM \m\o\n\t\h\s dd \d\a\y\s hh:mm:ss
   will give: 00 years 01 months 00 days 03:47:50
The time is ok but it should shows 00 months.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/excel/comments/2sq6mc/how_do_i_get_excel_to_count_more_than_31_days/cns97ii/

Answer (score 0):

You can split your result by whole part and decimal part and operate with them:

```
=INT(A1/86400) & " " & TEXT((A1/86400)-INT(A1/86400),"hh:mm:ss")
```

[image]

Comment: I need to use this results in a pivot table, this is why I was using a format on the column.  Using your formula is not working and it's giving me a #VALUE! error.

Comment: From what I understand, to work in a pivot table, the result of the calculated field must be numeric?!?  Thanks for your help